# SBT startup failing

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to setup a simple SBT project, but it is failing with an annoying error:

```
λ sbt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\name.surname\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\work\ScalaKafkaScripts\project
[error] [C:\work\ScalaKafkaScripts\build.sbt]:9: illegal start of simple expression
[error] [C:\work\ScalaKafkaScripts\build.sbt]:12: ')' expected but eof found.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Here are the full contents of `build.sbt`:

```
import Dependencies._

lazy val root =
    (project in file("."))
      .settings(
        inThisBuild(List(
          organization := "yo.jevramonitor",
          scalaVersion := "2.12.1",
        )),
        name := "ScalaKafkaScripts",
        libraryDependencies ++= allDeps
      )
```

And here are the contents of `Dependencies` file:

```
import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  lazy val kafka = "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.1.0"
  lazy val allDeps = Seq(kafka)
}
```

Here is the directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma in `scalaVersion := "2.12.1",`.  Like in Scala itself trailing commas are not allowed in SBT syntax, ie, you can have

```
Seq("foo", "bar")
```

but not

```
Seq("foo", "bar",)
```

Comment: ffs, sbt being horribly unhelpful with the error message :( Thanks a lot

Comment: Ironically, now if you use SBT 1 (which uses 2.12) then this would work as trailing commas are now supported.